# Bibtex numbers in references list, but parentheses in text

Tags: bibtex, natbib

How can I achieve a numbered bibliography in the references section, but still be able to use parenthesis style in text?

For example,

**Introduction**

Following *Eva and Wall (2008)*, we propose to do ...

**References**

[1] Eva, and E. Wall. Wall-E. Pixar Anim. Studios. In Movies (A113)-42-64, 2008.

Thanks a lot. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I think you want to mix the numeric citation style with the author-date bibliographic style.

Comment: Yes, I want to do that. Numeric + author date. Is that possible?

Comment: @bendervader I'm not sure, maybe creating your own bibliographic style.